# How to keep user logged in (store userId with AsyncStorage)

Tags: react-native, authentication, store, asyncstorage

I am able to Login using my username and password (hardcoded), however, after login in I want to fetch some data from an API which can be done only if I am authenticated. 
So, the question is how can I keep the user logged in?

I am not that good in React-Native so any help would be highly appreciated!

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,AsyncStorage, FlatList, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';


export default class BMPServer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       username: 'testuser', 
       password: 'mypasswordhere',
       signedIn: false,
      checkedSignIn: false 
      };


    this.getAllDocuments();

 }
getAllDocuments = () => {

  fetch('https://example.dk/rest/Login/Authenticate/?businessId=1&solutionId=1', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username : this.state.username,
              password : this.state.password,
            })
          }) 

        .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((responseDocs) => {

        console.log("YOU HAVE SUCCSFULLY LOGGED IN:", responseDocs) 

});}
```

Comment: Save the response to async storage , when user successfully logged in ! And when check if token is presented or not every time you boot up the app !

Comment: @Arvindh thanks for your answer. Can you provide a code example for it? Theoretically, I kinda know how it works but I am not able to put it in code.

Comment: @BurimSyla Never save sensitive data like username & password in Async Storage. You should be using authentication token (access & refresh token) and you should be using  encryption to protect those token.

Comment: @katwal-Dipak thanks for your suggestion but I am not concerned about security at the moment.

Comment: @BurimSyla you can use Redux to save user info. You can use redux-persist & white list particular reducer so it won't be deleted when app is closed and it can be accessed and notified though out the app whenever there is change in user info state.

Comment: @katwal-Dipak can you provide me with an example. Please use my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a solution to my problem. **Fetch()** sets cookies automatically but you have to include this when fetching:  **credentials: 'include'**.
There is no need for AsyncStorage or anything like that, it is just a waste of time and unfortunately even after a week of search about this problem I was not able to find out a solution anywhere on the internet, and obviously the solution is very very simple.

See code below for details:

```
getAllDocuments = () => {
    fetch('LOGIN_URL_HERE', {     //*HERE I AM AUTHENTICATING*
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: 'myemail',
        password: 'mypassword'
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((res) => {

        console.log("This is the user:", res)

        fetch('DOCUMENTS_URL_HERE', {    //*HERE I AM FETCHING DOCUMENTS AFTER I HAVE SUCCESSFULLY AUTHENTICATED*
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          credentials: 'include',     //USE THIS TO SET COOKIES
          body: JSON.stringify({
            lastServerSyncDateAsLong: 0,
            inserted: {},
            edited: {},
            deleted: {}
          })
        })
     .then((res) => res.json())

          .then((ressDocs) => {
            console.log("THESE ARE ALL DOCUMENTS FETCHED FROM API:", ressDocs)
          })

      })

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your getting the token on successful authentication.

```js
    import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

    fetch('https://example.dk/rest/Login/Authenticate/?businessId=1&solutionId=1', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username : this.state.username,
              password : this.state.password,
            })
          }) 

        .then((response) => AsyncStorage.setItem(LOGIN_TOKEN, response))

      .then((responseDocs) => {

        console.log("YOU HAVE SUCCSFULLY LOGGED IN:", responseDocs) 

     });}
```

So, now you have token stored at asyncstorage. So, on your initial screen for example, splash screen give a condition on to check if the token is presented by using

```
AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGIN_TOKEN);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me where should I put the userId value? And just pretend there is no splash screen, I just wanna log in as soon as I start the app, that's it.

Comment: You mean userId as token , that you get from the response of successful auth ?

Comment: yeah I get a user id with 3 digits ex. '123' . I  dont get any token, at least I cant see any in the console log. I dont know if that is already the token!

Comment: So are you using userId for any case ? So what i am understanding is that your getting userId as ex '123' when there is an successful auth right ?

Comment: yes, that's correct. And that userId remains the same permanently. Every time I am authenticated, the userId will be the same. P.S remember I am authenticating only one user which credentials are hardcoded.

Comment: Actually, what your expecting is that every time user opens the app the user should be authenticated ? is that what your asking ?

Comment: Yes, every time I open my app, I should be automatically authenticated.

Comment: Then, you should be calling `getAllDocuments` function on everytime you boot the app. what navigation ur using ? and whats your initial screen ?

Comment: the thing is that I am authenticating but I want to keep that state, because the second step is fetch some data which cannot be fetched if I am currently not authenticated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189181/discussion-between-arvindh-and-burim-syla).

Comment: please go back to chat

Answer (score 0):

React navigation has an authentication flow example with their Switch Navigator at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Basically you have a special navigator for switching between logged and not logged user, since AsyncStorage persists, there should be no problem.

Here's the code, run it. It's pretty simple :)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Please sign in',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  };
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome to the app!',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Show me more of the app" onPress={this._showMoreApp} />
        <Button title="Actually, sign me out :)" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _showMoreApp = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Other');
  };

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

class OtherScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Lots of features here',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="I'm done, sign me out" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };
}

class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

Comment: please use my code to elaborate your example better.

Comment: await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc'); Can you explain what comes in 'abc' ?

Comment: 'abc' is the value that you set 'userToken' to. So to use the aforementioned code, you'd replace that with your authentication logic.